# Without bio-tech is it possible to updgrade/evolute human race under applied conditions

Tags: evolution

I am building a city. A city full of athletes.
These athletes are world class 100m sprinters of Olympic level or any renowned sports organization. 50,000 of such athletes are brought together under these conditions:

1. They will continue their training for their entire life.
2. No contact with the outside world. They will only know each other, forever.
3. Access to all modern day amenities, technology(phones, PCs, etc), medical aid (no steroids), just not biotech!

Here's where it gets interesting:
As and when they mate, their offspring have to be trained by their parents to be the fastest. Their goal in life is to be the **fastest sprinter in the city**

And they do this for 'n' generations.

What are the possibilities? Will they be able to run a 100m in under 5 seconds, or is there a threshold?  Will they evolve or not?  If yes, How long will it take for this society to evolve?  And ultimately would they differ (in performance only) with the humans of our society?

If I want to build a city of swimmers, what am I to expect?

- City of Physical theories
- City of bodybuilders
- City of beauty
- City of chess players[Or any intellectual capability]

Comment: For Evolution, you are missing the selection pressure. Just taking people who are good at something and letting them have children will not result in children who are even better at it. And of course, letting them train all the time will only result in a better understanding where their limits are, but it will (probably) not increase the running ability of their children.

Comment: They already differ in sprinting performance from the average human of our society. We have reason to believe that athletic performance is partly genetically inherited, so most likely their offspring will be, on the average, better than the average human. We also know for sure that athletic performance is (a) [pleiotropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiotropy) and (b) only partially determined genetically. And for evolution to work you need to kill those children which don't run as fast as you would like.

Comment: @AlexP Well, you could exile those children instead - perhaps into whichever other city they "test into", or to the countryside. (Somebody has to feed these cities, surely.)

Comment: I doubt there are 50 thousand world class sprinters. Else the Olympic games would be much more crowded. But first of all, welcome to worldbuilding. Please note we try to focus on well defined problems, while your question seems to be quite broad.

Answer (score 2):

While it's likely your city will produce the best sprinter in most generations (assuming someones taking care of feeding/clothing them etc...) they will not evolve into better athletes in any reasonable timescale.

the main-problem is that any training done by one generation will not pass on the effects to the next generation. This is the difference between Lamarckian evolution and Darwinian evolution. Before we knew the root cause of evolution multiple theories tired to explain it. Lamarcks model of evolution worked along your lines with traits gained through practice over the lives of the parents being passed to the children the problem is that simply doesn't happen. in truth you need to actively change the D.N.A. of a creature to evolve it and to do that you need either Darwinian evolution (The bad runners die off and their bad running genes leave the gene pool) or you need biotech

that being said if a basic knowledge of genetics exists in your city its possible that in each generation there will be something of an evolutionary selection towards better athletes as people  mate more with better athletes to have the best possible children at running the hundred metres. Even then though the amount of time it would take to bring the hundred metres down to five seconds would be several hundred times longer than even the longest lived of human society.

that's not to say of course that a city of dedicated healthy athletes wouldn't produce good runners I don't doubt with enough social pressure, sports science and good initial selection a large portion of the cities population could break the current world record.

as for your other cities:

a city of body builders or swimmers has the same problem as the city of runners, it could produce a lot of muscle but ultimately wouldn't evolve and reach new ground.

a city of beauty would be flat out impossible because peoples standards of beauty change dramatically even over the course a few generations.

a city of chess players would by far see the best success, chess is a complicated game and its depths are by no means plumed its likely your city would find many many new strategies, methods of teaching and ways of thinking about the game that would improve their ability to play chess (that being said an child from the outside world raised in such a society would still be just as good as a Nth generationer).

I'm not 100% sure what you mean about a city of physical theories?

Comment: great answer! I wont say I am not disappointed that the city wont produce out of the world athletes. BTW physical theories meaning theories of physics, laws, discoveries. Basically 50,000 hawkings

Comment: ah i see, well with enough time obviously a whole bunch of smart people will probably be able to make scientific breakthroughs especially considering that the comparatively short time that the scientific method has been used. though this is one city that would be much more effective to connect to the outside world to allow for ideas to spread